# SDDM cannot display "Password expired. You must change it now"

Tags: kde, password, sddm

I have ubuntu 18.04 with KDE 5 installed, using SDDM. I try to setup new user account on Kerberos and set the inital password expired, hence forced users to change password on the first login. The SDDM login screen will hang for a while without showing anything. I look at the syslog and clearly it shows " Authentication information: "Password expired. You must change it now.".

Is there anyway that SDDM can let user change password on the login screen?